# Methods inside namespace c#

Tags: c#, class, syntax, namespaces

Is there any way to call a function that is inside of a namespace without declaring the class inside c#.

For Example, if I had 2 methods that are the exact same and should be used in all of my C# projects, is there any way to just take those functions and make it into a dll and just say 'Using myTwoMethods' on top and start using the methods without declaring the class?

Right now, I do:
MyClass.MyMethod();

I want to do:
MyMethod();

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't declare methods outside of a class, but you can do this using a static helper class in a Class Library Project.

```
public static class HelperClass
{
    public static void HelperMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Usage (after adding a reference to your Class Library).

```
HelperClass.HelperMethod();
```

Comment: Is there a way to call "HelperMethod()" without the helperclass?

Comment: There is not. Methods must be contained within a class or struct.

Comment: If you declare `using static HelperClass` you can call `HelperMethod()`

Answer (score 34):

Update for 2015: 
No you cannot create "free functions" in C#, but starting with C# 6 you'll be able to call static functions without mentioning the class name. [C# 6 will have the "using static" feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) allowing this syntax:

```
static class MyClass {
     public static void MyMethod();
}
```

SomeOtherFile.cs:

```
using static MyClass;

void SomeMethod() {
    MyMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what type of method we are talking, you could look into extension methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

This allows you to easily add extra functionality to existing objects.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the suggestion to use extension methods, you could make the method an extension method off of System.Object, from which all classes derive. I would not advocate this, but pertaining to your question this may be an answer.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
      public static void MyMethod(this System.Object o)
      {
        // Do something here.
      }
    }
}
```

You could now write code like `MyMethod();` anywhere you have a `using SomeNamespace;`, unless you are in a static method (then you would have to do `Extensions.MyMethod(null)`).

Comment: I am not able to access MyMethod without calling 'Extensions.MyMethod()' within my Form_load of another class. THanks anyway.

Comment: This seemed really cool until I remembered that the Main function in C# is required to be static.